# jquery unbind special event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

There is my code that I want to alert "test" once when mousemove , and then remove the mousemove event , but i use `unbind()` seem not work, can somebody help me ??

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $(document).mousemove( function(){
    alert( "test" );
    $(document).unbind("mousemove");
  });
});
```

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mqk9W/). But you could use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to shorten your code.

Comment: thansk @F.Calderan @James Allardice for help,I'm try to use `.one()` and it's work now , but `.unbind()` still not work !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [$.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind a one-time use event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).one("mousemove", function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks `Mattias Buelens` I used this method and it is work now, thanks your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think its now **on** and **off** instead of **bind/unbind**

Can you please try

```
$(document).off("mousemove");
```

Comment: While it's true that `on` and `off` are now the preferred methods, `unbind` will still work so this is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: Actually unbind will just call the off method, so better to make it a best practice to just use off()

Comment: I'm try to use `.off()`, but it can not work, then I try this `.one()`  and  it work. Thanks every one for help me, I appreciate it.